# Tkinter: Create an homepage look like

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to create for my GUI an homepage like look, I've manege to arrive at this point, but now I'm little stuck. What I'd like to achieve is change the bottom_box when clicking the button that link to Page One or Page Two.
Thanks for your help!
**EDIT** I've worked on it a little bit and I've arrived at this point. When running my code now I get this error :
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/folder/01.py", line 17, in 
button1 = tk.Button(container, text="Go to Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined!

This is my edited code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PageOne import PageOne
from PageTwo import PageTwo


class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        
        ###MENU FRAME
        left_frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, bg= "white", relief="solid", highlightthickness=2)
        left_frame.pack(side="left", expand=False, fill="y")
        right_frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, bg= "white", relief="solid", highlightthickness=2)
        right_frame.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both")
        container = tk.Frame(left_frame, borderwidth=1, bg= "white", relief="solid")
        container.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)
        button1 = tk.Button(container, text="Go to Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        button2 = tk.Button(container, text="Go to Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button2.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        
        ###TOP
        top_box = tk.Frame(right_frame, borderwidth=1, bg= "white", relief="solid")
        top_box.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        label_top = tk.Label(top_box, text="Title Logo", bg= "white")
        label_top.pack()
        
        ###BOTTOM
        bottom_box = tk.Frame(right_frame, borderwidth=1, bg= "green", relief="solid")
        bottom_box.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        label_bott = tk.Label(bottom_box, text=" Logo", bg= "white")
        

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=bottom_box, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1200x650")
    MainApp(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Page 1

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        label_pg1 = tk.Label(self, text="page 1", bg= "white")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Page 2

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont



class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        label_pg2 = tk.Label(self, text="page 2", bg= "white")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had a bit of trouble running the code as is. I see that there are parts that should be ditched before posting here. For instance there should be only one initalization of Tk().
Also be consistent how you import tkinter. Preferable always import is as `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was having trouble understating why it didn't work because it didn't give me any problem. I've tried posting a previous version that hopefully works. Thank you  again!

Comment: I've move on a little with my code, but I've still having problem. If someone could indicate me what I'm doing wrong I'll be very grateful! Thank you all again